# SQL - Convert columns to rows (use a pivot or other means)?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am struggling with reformatting an answer set I have from a query.  This is data from a monitoring tool that I am calculating a monthly average along with a linear regression projection.  This is all performed in other functions and working fine.  These functions all feed the below two tables with the final data that I use.  The only thing I am currently grappling with is re-formatting the output to show more columns than rows.

To start, let me give you the sample data that I'm working with Using SQL Server 2008R2

```
create table finalactual(Target varchar(100), MonthNum int, [Actual] real)
create table finalprojection(Target varchar(100), MonthNum int, [monthname] varchar(20), [Forecast] real)

Insert into finalprojection values ('C:\', 2, 'February', 65609.29)
Insert into finalprojection values ('C:\', 3, 'March',  65850.27)
Insert into finalprojection values ('C:\', 4, 'April',  66091.26)
Insert into finalprojection values ('C:\', 5, 'May',    66332.25)                                     
Insert into finalprojection values ('C:\', 6, 'June',   66573.23)
Insert into finalprojection values ('C:\', 7, 'July',   66814.22)
Insert into finalprojection values ('C:\', 8, 'August', 67055.2)
Insert into finalprojection values ('C:\', 9, 'September',  67296.19)
Insert into finalprojection values ('C:\', 10, 'October',   67537.17)
Insert into finalprojection values ('C:\', 11, 'November',  67778.16)
Insert into finalprojection values ('C:\', 12, 'December',  68019.14)
Insert into finalprojection values ('C:\', 13, 'January',   68260.13)
Insert into finalprojection values ('E:\', 2, 'February', 385251.0)
Insert into finalprojection values ('E:\', 3, 'March',  401171.1)
Insert into finalprojection values ('E:\', 4, 'April',  417091.2)
Insert into finalprojection values ('E:\', 5, 'May',    433011.3)                                     
Insert into finalprojection values ('E:\', 6, 'June',   448937.3)
Insert into finalprojection values ('E:\', 7, 'July',   464851.4)
Insert into finalprojection values ('E:\', 8, 'August', 480771.4)
Insert into finalprojection values ('E:\', 9, 'September',  496691.5)
Insert into finalprojection values ('E:\', 10, 'October',   512611.6)
Insert into finalprojection values ('E:\', 11, 'November',  528531.6)
Insert into finalprojection values ('E:\', 12, 'December',  544451.8)
Insert into finalprojection values ('E:\', 13, 'January',   560371.8)                                      

Insert into finalactual values ('C:\', 2, 62927.88)
Insert into finalactual values ('C:\', 3, 64534.62)
Insert into finalactual values ('C:\', 4, 67215.3)
Insert into finalactual values ('C:\', 5, 70991.05)
Insert into finalactual values ('C:\', 6, 69857.11)
Insert into finalactual values ('C:\', 7, 64440.7)
Insert into finalactual values ('C:\', 8, 64359.08)
Insert into finalactual values ('E:\', 2, 382691.4)                                     
Insert into finalactual values ('E:\', 3, 400543.9)                                     
Insert into finalactual values ('E:\', 4, 418160.4)                                     
Insert into finalactual values ('E:\', 5, 435643.2)                                     
Insert into finalactual values ('E:\', 6, 451213.5)                                     
Insert into finalactual values ('E:\', 7, 466608.2)                                     
Insert into finalactual values ('E:\', 8, 476218.2)
```

If you run the following query

```
select a.target, a.monthnum as 'Month Value', case when a.monthnum <= 12 then 
a.monthnum else a.monthnum-12 end as 'Month Number', a.monthname as [Month],

b.Actual as 'Actual', a.forecast from finalprojection a
left join
finalactual b on a.Target = b.Target AND a.monthnum = b.MonthNum
order by Target ASC, [Month Value] ASC
```

The resulting answer set looks like the following:

```
target  Month Value Month Number    Month   Actual      forecast
C:\     2           2              February 62927.88    65609.29
C:\     3           3              March    64534.62    65850.27
C:\     4           4              April    67215.3     66091.26
C:\     5           5              May      70991.05    66332.25
C:\     6           6              June     69857.11    66573.23
C:\     7           7              July     64440.7     66814.22
C:\     8           8              August   64359.08    67055.2
C:\     9           9              September    NULL    67296.19
C:\     10          10             October      NULL    67537.17
C:\     11          11             November     NULL    67778.16
C:\     12          12             December     NULL    68019.14
C:\     13          1              January      NULL    68260.13
E:\     2           2              February 382691.4    385251
E:\     3           3              March    400543.9    401171.1
E:\     4           4              April    418160.4    417091.2
E:\     5           5              May      435643.2    433011.3
E:\     6           6              June     451213.5    448931.3
E:\     7           7              July     466608.2    464851.4
E:\     8           8              August   476218.2    480771.4
E:\     9           9              September    NULL    496691.5
E:\     10          10             October      NULL    512611.6
E:\     11          11             November     NULL    528531.6
E:\     12          12             December     NULL    544451.8
E:\     13          1              January      NULL    560371.8
```

This is fine, as I have 6 or 7 months of real data, combined with a linear regression calculation extending an additional 6 months (which is why the "null" values for Sept to Jan) under actual.

What I would like to have for the output would be something along this line:

```
Target  A/F  Feb   Mar   Apr   May   Jun   Jul   Aug   Sep   Oct   Nov   Dec   Jan
C:\      A   62927 64534 67215 70991 69857 64440 64359 NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL
C:\      F   65609 65850 66091 66332 66573 66814 67055 67296 67537 67778 68019 68260
```

I have abbreviated the decimals along with the A/F (meaning Actual vs Forecast) for space reasons.  I have also left off the E:\ drive...again, in the interest of brevity.

One issue that will likely be a problem is that the starting month (in the example above, it is February) will be dynamic.  Meaning if the query runs in September, the first month will be March...October will have April as the first month...and so on.

I have created a SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/901c4/1 to save some time for you all.

I thank you all for your help in advance.

Updated info related to the sliding date need:

Hi guys...all excellent solutions.

Let me explain what I meant by the starting month.

Running the report today (in August) will need to have the first month of the result set being February and ending in January of 2015.  This is because the report reaches back 6 months in history to gather the monthly results.  From there, it extends (the linear regression) past the actual data for an additional 6 months (forecast).  This is one quirk that I really need to accommodate (i know...pain in the butt).

So if this query were to run next month (in September), the starting month would need to be March and end in February 2015.  If I run the report in October, the starting month would need to be April, which would increment through May of 2015.  I hope that clarifies how that sliding scale of the months needs to be presented.

Just adding a clarification on how the month scale is being used:
the column "month value" is how the output is presented in the necessary order.  This column will increment based from the starting month and continue for 12 increments.  For example:
If the query is run in August (like the above sample data) the starting month for the data will be February (Run date is "month value" of 8 data begins 6 months prior or "month value" of 2.  This sets up the order you see above where "month value" begins in the answer set at 2 and continues to 13.  Part of the routine that generates these tables evaluates the "month value" column and generates the "month number" column (if it is < 12 then use the original value...if > 12 then subtract 12).  This is why the rows that have a "month value" of 13 show a "month number" of 1 which, using a datename() conversion returns "January".
If this same query were to be run next month (September or month 10), everything would shift by 1 in the answer set.  The starting "month value" would be 3 or March and the end "month value" would be 14 or February (the system will subtract 12 from the value over 12 to give us the 2).  In this case, the answer set returned would look like this:

```
target  Month Value Month Number    Month   Actual      forecast
C:\     3           3              March    62927.88    65609.29
C:\     4           4              April    64534.62    65850.27
C:\     5           5              May      67215.3     66091.26
C:\     6           6              June     70991.05    66332.25
C:\     7           7              July     69857.11    66573.23
C:\     8           8              August   64440.7     66814.22
C:\     9           9              Sept     64359.08    67055.2
C:\     10          10             October      NULL    67296.19
C:\     11          11             November     NULL    67537.17
C:\     12          12             December     NULL    67778.16
C:\     13          1              January      NULL    68019.14
C:\     14          2              February     NULL    68260.13
```

Note:  removed the E:\ drive for brevity above

The pivoted answer should then look like below:

```
Target  A/F  Mar   Apr   May   Jun   Jul   Aug   Sep   Oct   Nov   Dec   Jan   Feb
C:\      A   62927 64534 67215 70991 69857 64440 64359 NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL
C:\      F   65609 65850 66091 66332 66573 66814 67055 67296 67537 67778 68019 68260
```

The people seeing the output don't need to see years mentioned as they understand the report is showing a 12 month span of real and forecast data...so as a "January" shows up, they know that they are spanning into a new year.

I hope this helps give you the idea of how the answer set is structured.

Again...thank you for the current ideas...very good stuff.

Comment: You say you need a sliding month as the final result but you've included data that is month number, do you actually have a date aka month/year?

Comment: hi..no I don't...the increment is based on the "Month Value" column which keeps the correct order.  Part of the output of the procedure calculates if the month increment is over 12 it then subtracts 12...so "month value" of 13 actually represents month 1 or January.

Comment: so to add to that, if the query is run in September (month 9), the "month value" column would start at March (month value 3) which is 6 months prior and continue to 14 (14-12 = 2) or February.  It uses a datename() to convert the integer "month value" to the month name from there.

Comment: How do you know then what would be `2014` or `2015`?  You've got no indicator of what is in each year.  Without some sort of indicator, you are going to have a tough time trying to make this dynamic.  Your current structure is very difficult to maintain, I'd strongly suggest using an actual date.

Comment: They are not worried about that as when it increments past a December, they know they are looking at the next year...saved me some added problems with that

Comment: @Buckwheattb Whoever designed that should be fired.

Comment: @Buckwheattb But data in the tables is not inherently ordered at this point you could have multiple entries for each month value, but no way to tell what year that value is coming from.  Without some sort of indicator as to what is "later" you will have a hard time doing this dynamically.

Comment: Do the tables always contain 12 months' worth of data (6 past months + 6 months starting from the current one)? If not, I think the issue @bluefeet keeps asking about is how you determine whether the current month is Month Value = 8 or Month Value = 20 or Month Value = 32 etc.

Comment: It will always be 12 months.  Maybe we can simplify this by forgetting the actual months, and pivot off of the "month value" column...wherever that column starts (1, 2, 3 or 22)...doesn't matter...it will always increase by 12 from there...does that simplify it more?

Comment: @Buckwheattb I've added a dynamic sql version to my answer. You'll have to play with the ordering of the columns based on your actual data but it should get you started.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While the other two answers will get you the result that you want, I should do this slightly different. You can `unpivot` the data in your `Actual` and `Forecast` columns first, then pivot the months.

You didn't specify what version of SQL Server you are using but starting in SQL Server 2005+ you can use `CROSS APPLY` to unpivot.

The basic syntax would be similar to:

```
select a.target, 
  Left(a.monthname, 3) as [Month],
  AorF,
  value
from finalprojection a
left join finalactual b 
  on a.Target = b.Target 
 AND a.monthnum = b.MonthNum
cross apply
(
  select 'A', b.Actual union all
  select 'F', a.forecast
) c(AorF, value);
```

See [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/901c4/6). This is going to convert your multiple columns `Actual` and `Forecast` into multiple rows.  Once the data is in this format, you can easily pivot the months making the full script:

```
select target, 
  AorF,
  Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul,
  Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec
from
(
  select a.target, 
    Left(a.monthname, 3) as [Month],
    AorF,
    value
  from finalprojection a
  left join finalactual b 
    on a.Target = b.Target 
    AND a.monthnum = b.MonthNum
  cross apply
  (
    select 'A', b.Actual union all
    select 'F', a.forecast
  ) c(AorF, value)
)  d
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for month in (Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul,
                Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec)
) piv
order by target;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/901c4/7/0). This gives a final result of:

```
| TARGET | AORF |           JAN |            FEB |            MAR |           APR |          MAY |           JUN |            JUL |          AUG |        SEP |          OCT |         NOV |          DEC |
|--------|------|---------------|----------------|----------------|---------------|--------------|---------------|----------------|--------------|------------|--------------|-------------|--------------|
|    C:\ |    A |        (null) | 62927.87890625 | 64534.62109375 |  67215.296875 | 70991.046875 |  69857.109375 | 64440.69921875 | 64359.078125 |     (null) |       (null) |      (null) |       (null) |
|    C:\ |    F | 68260.1328125 |  65609.2890625 |  65850.2734375 | 66091.2578125 |     66332.25 | 66573.2265625 |    66814.21875 | 67055.203125 | 67296.1875 | 67537.171875 | 67778.15625 | 68019.140625 |
|    E:\ |    A |        (null) |   382691.40625 |   400543.90625 |  418160.40625 |  435643.1875 |      451213.5 |    466608.1875 |  476218.1875 |     (null) |       (null) |      (null) |       (null) |
|    E:\ |    F |   560371.8125 |         385251 |   401171.09375 |   417091.1875 |  433011.3125 |   448937.3125 |   464851.40625 | 480771.40625 |   496691.5 | 512611.59375 |  528531.625 |  544451.8125 |
```

If you needs the columns to be ordered differently based on a the start month, then you'll have to use dynamic SQL similar to:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @start int

set @start = 8

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Left(monthname, 3)) 
                    from finalprojection
                    where MonthNum > (@start - 6)
                      and MonthNum <= (@start + 6)
                    group by monthNum,MonthName
                    order by MonthNum
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query = 'SELECT target, AorF,' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
              select a.target, 
                Left(a.monthname, 3) as [Month],
                AorF,
                value
              from finalprojection a
              left join finalactual b 
                on a.Target = b.Target 
                AND a.monthnum = b.MonthNum
              cross apply
              (
                select ''A'', b.Actual union all
                select ''F'', a.forecast
              ) c (AorF, value)
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for month in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p 
            order by target'

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

See [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ea5e3/13)

Comment: I think this is the answer...putting it in place now and will let you know.  I made two changes though:  set@start = (select max(monthnum) from finalactual) -- this grabs the current month that the report is running from.  Also changed the "where MonthNum >= (@start - 6) ...Thank you very much...was struggling with the dynamic end of the pivot.  Will update this in a few minutes with a final.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand exactly what you mean by the columns are in different order based on the month this is run. If you can explain that I can help figure out a solution to that. This query looks lengthy but it is actually quite simple once you break it down. This is using what is known as a cross tab. To break the Actual and Forecast I did them separately and then used a UNION to put them back together.

```
with MyCte as
(
    select a.target
        , a.monthnum 
        , b.Actual
        , a.forecast 
        , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by a.target order by a.monthnum) as RowNum
    from finalprojection a
    left join finalactual b on a.Target = b.Target AND a.monthnum = b.MonthNum
)

select Target
    , 'A' as [A/F]
    , max(case when monthnum = 2 then Actual end) as Feb
    , max(case when monthnum = 3 then Actual end) as Mar
    , max(case when monthnum = 4 then Actual end) as Apr
    , max(case when monthnum = 5 then Actual end) as May
    , max(case when monthnum = 6 then Actual end) as Jun
    , max(case when monthnum = 7 then Actual end) as Jul
    , max(case when monthnum = 8 then Actual end) as Aug
    , max(case when monthnum = 9 then Actual end) as Sep
    , max(case when monthnum = 10 then Actual end) as Oct
    , max(case when monthnum = 11 then Actual end) as Nov
    , max(case when monthnum = 12 then Actual end) as Dec
    , max(case when monthnum = 1 then Actual end) as Jan
from MyCte
group by Target

union all

select Target
    , 'F' as [A/F]
    , max(case when monthnum = 2 then Forecast end) as Feb
    , max(case when monthnum = 3 then Forecast end) as Mar
    , max(case when monthnum = 4 then Forecast end) as Apr
    , max(case when monthnum = 5 then Forecast end) as May
    , max(case when monthnum = 6 then Forecast end) as Jun
    , max(case when monthnum = 7 then Forecast end) as Jul
    , max(case when monthnum = 8 then Forecast end) as Aug
    , max(case when monthnum = 9 then Forecast end) as Sep
    , max(case when monthnum = 10 then Forecast end) as Oct
    , max(case when monthnum = 11 then Forecast end) as Nov
    , max(case when monthnum = 12 then Forecast end) as Dec
    , max(case when monthnum = 1 then Forecast end) as Jan
from MyCte
group by Target
order by Target, [A/F]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pivot table based on the query you gave the results from. It does Actuals and Forecast separately. To have the columns in a different order you would need to select them in a different order.

```
SELECT Target, 'Actual' AS [A/F]
    , [February], [March], [April], [May], [June], [July], [August]
    , [September], [October], [November], [December], [January]
FROM ( 
        SELECT [Target], [Month], [Actual] FROM (
            select a.target, a.monthnum as 'Month Value', case when a.monthnum <= 12 then 
            a.monthnum else a.monthnum-12 end as 'Month Number', a.monthname as [Month],
            b.Actual as 'Actual', a.forecast 
            from @finalprojection a left join @finalactual b on a.Target = b.Target AND a.monthnum = b.MonthNum
         ) AS YourTable 
     ) AS SourceTable
PIVOT (
         SUM([Actual]) FOR [Month] IN ([February], [March], [April], [May], [June], [July], [August]
                                     , [September], [October], [November], [December], [January])
       ) AS PivotData
UNION ALL 
SELECT Target, 'Forecast' AS [A/F]
    , [February], [March], [April], [May], [June], [July], [August]
    , [September], [October], [November], [December], [January]
FROM ( 
        SELECT [Target], [Month], [forecast] FROM (
            select a.target, a.monthnum as 'Month Value', case when a.monthnum <= 12 then 
            a.monthnum else a.monthnum-12 end as 'Month Number', a.monthname as [Month],
            b.Actual as 'Actual', a.forecast 
            from @finalprojection a left join @finalactual b on a.Target = b.Target AND a.monthnum = b.MonthNum
            ) AS YourTable 
        ) AS SourceTable
PIVOT (
          SUM([forecast]) FOR [Month] IN ([February], [March], [April], [May], [June], [July], [August]
                                        , [September], [October], [November], [December], [January])
      ) AS PivotData
```

When I ran this with the data you provided I got the following:

```
Target  A/F         February        March           April           May             June            July            August          September   October         November    December        January
C:\     Actual      62927.87890625  64534.62109375  67215.296875    70991.046875    69857.109375    64440.69921875  64359.078125    NULL        NULL            NULL        NULL            NULL
E:\     Actual      382691.40625    400543.90625    418160.40625    435643.1875     451213.5        466608.1875     476218.1875     NULL        NULL            NULL        NULL            NULL
C:\     Forecast    65609.2890625   65850.2734375   66091.2578125   66332.25        66573.2265625   66814.21875     67055.203125    67296.1875  67537.171875    67778.15625 68019.140625    68260.1328125
E:\     Forecast    385251          401171.09375    417091.1875     433011.3125     448937.3125     464851.40625    480771.40625    496691.5    512611.59375    528531.625  544451.8125     560371.8125
```

Note that the pivot uses a sum of all the data - so could give you dodgy results if you have more than one entry for each target & month. This is in there because the pivot needs something to group on. This might be where your problem of the order of the months comes in, but I need you to be more specific there to be sure.